# IE8 and Below inline-block CSS

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

So I know that IE8 and below does not like `inline-block` but I read that `inline` should result in the same behavior. So I modified copied my `main.css` to `main-ie8below.css` and changed all `inline-block` to `inline`. I use the following code to try and achieve this:

```
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/main-ie8below.css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gt IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/main.css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/main.css" />
         <!--<![endif]-->
```

However, this is not working. It seems that my if statements are incorrect. Is that the case, or am I missing something else?

Here is the HMTL in question (useless stuff removed):

```
    <nav id="main_nav" role="navigation"><!--
                            <div><a href=""><img src=""  /></a></div><!--
                    --><div><a href=""><img src=""  /></a></div><!--
                    --><div><a href=""><img src=""  /></a></div><!--
                    --><div><a href=""><img src=""  /></a></div><!--
                    -->
```

Here is a fiddle, except without images:

http://jsfiddle.net/bqXsU/

Comment: When dealing with IE features detection I believe the best approach would be to stick to the HTML5 Boilerplate way:
`<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->`
and in your `main.css` add a rule for `.lt-ie8 .my-inline-block-element{}`

Comment: What exactly is not working? A screenshot or jsfiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: I suspect that your problem may be that padding/margins are not being added (they don't work on inline elements) I didn't know about zoom for IE8 and below though, that may well be your problem too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the fault of HTML5 elements not being recognized by IE8. By adding HTML5shiv I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this way:

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

I guess you missed the `zoom: 1` part. And if you are coupling with the existing stylesheet, which goes for all the IE versions and modern browsers, it is good to use this way:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```

But the problem is that, your CSS might not validate.

---

I don't understand, which part is the one you didn't understand. Let me explain the three things I used.

1. **Star Hack:** Prepending a `*` in front of the style rule, will make it only visible to IE 7 and below.
2. **Validation Issue:** The rules `*zoom` and `*display` are not valid CSS properties.
3. **How does this work?** In IE 7 and below, this `zoom: 1;` will trigger the `hasLayout` property of the element, thereby making it available the `width`, `height`, `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: Could you explain the last part in a bit more detail?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Added explanation. Please lemme know if you don't understand anything. :)

Comment: Unfortuntately, it is not fixing it for IE8, i posted the html snippet that i was using `inline-block` for. Its essentially a horizontal navigation bar

Comment: @thatidiotguy IE 8 actually likes `inline-block`. :) I don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: alright, im going to put together a fiddle to show what I am doing and maybe reask the question, thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Sure, anytime.. :) Fiddle would be great... Do update me, so that I can figure out what's stopping you! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24582/discussion-between-thatidiotguy-and-praveen-kumar)