# Inline-block isn't working with ie8?

Tags: html, block, css

Please view the this website [Here](http://webfro.gs/south/tour/national_presence.html) with IE8. You may notice at the bottom, there are arrows on either side of some icons.

Locally, the arrows appear on either side, but they're squished to about 10 pixels and they're supposed to be 60px by 44px. When viewed on the server, they don't appear squished, but they're above and below the icons. Not sure which direction to go here.

When viewed in Chrome, they appear fine, and they're on either side of the 3 icons, as they should be. They get all messed up in IE8. I've been playing around with this CSS (inline-block), to no avail.

```
#nav_arrow {
    display: inline-block !important;   
    }
```

**Here is the HTML for that area...**

```
    <p align="center">

        <div id="nav_arrow">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icons/arrow_left.png" width="60" height="44"></a>
            <img src="images/spacer-10px.png"></div>

        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icons/home_75x75.png" alt="" title="Welcome!"></a>
            <img src="images/spacer-10px.png">

        <a href="national_presence.html"><img src="images/icons/locations_75x75.png" alt="" title="Our Locations!"></a>
            <img src="images/spacer-10px.png">

        <a href="accreditation.html"><img src="images/icons/accreditation_75x75.png" alt="" title="Our Accreditation!"></a>
            <img src="images/spacer-10px.png">

        <div id="nav_arrow">
        <a href="accreditation.html"><img src="images/icons/arrow_right.png" width="60" height="44"></a>
            <img src="images/spacer-10px.png"></div>


    </p>
```

I have tried moving the  tags around, wrapping everything in one container, changing the doctype, but I've had no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#nav_arrow {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I did it and it worked. But what did it do. What's the zoom attribute?

Comment: I don't know, but I see this here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898928/ie8-and-below-inline-block-css

You have to search more! Please, mark my answer as solved, thanks. ;)

Comment: If you found the answer elsewhere on stackoverflow you should have just added that as a comment on the question, especially since your answer doesn't explain why adding `zoom:1` fixes the problem! Also asking for answers to be marked as solved should really be avoided. It is clear the @JaredNewnam has accepted previous questions so knows how it works.

Comment: I have just accepted it. It wasn't an image issue actually... I was viewing this site in IE8, which requires Compatibility Mode be enabled. Once I enabled it, everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is someone unexpected:

```
img { max-width: 100%;
```

IE 8 behaves differently than other browsers with `max-width` on images. It's worth looking at the specs:

```
 If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the
 resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.
```

Which is the case here. So to be fair, IE isn't exactly wrong.

The suggested fix

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

is a hack for IE < 8. The result is similar to `display: inline-block`. And it's a happy coincidence that `max-width` on images works as expected in IE 7 compatibility mode. Maybe in IE 7 too, I don't know. So you kind of trigger IE 7 rendering mode with this hack and that's why it works.